# How to strip height and width tags from a html using Python?

Tags: python

My html is comprised of image tag like this:

```
 <img alt="Alla_dj01" height="333" src="http://getfile0.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-02-01/kjyqxkaqBICwbidlzEeCurhwpcilIGzDDcFrmlCcGDkftlbsedenbAGpFdbo/ALLA_DJ01.jpg.scaled500.jpg" width="500"
```

I want to completely remove width and height from the tags. I can use replace and remove the tags, but the height and width values keep changing, hence it is a bit confusing how to cleanly remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a single element like this, you should be able to use regular-expression based search and replace quite easily.

See the [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function, which does this.

As a starting point, I'd try with something like:

```
stripped = re.sub(r'(height|width)=\"\d+\"', "", old_html)
```

You can improve this further to support single quotes for the attribute values, not assume that the value will be all digits, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [40]: import lxml.html as lh

In [41]: html = '''<img alt="Alla_dj01" height="333" src="http://getfile0.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-02-01/kjyqxkaqBICwbidlzEeCurhwpcilIGzDDcFrmlCcGDkftlbsedenbAGpFdbo/ALLA_DJ01.jpg.scaled500.jpg" width="500"'''

In [42]: doc = lh.fromstring(html)

In [43]: for img in doc.xpath('//img'):
    ...:     for a in ['width','height']:
    ...:         img.attrib.pop(a)  # img.attrib is basically a dict
    ...:         

In [44]: print lh.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<img alt="Alla_dj01" src="http://getfile0.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-02-01/kjyqxkaqBICwbidlzEeCurhwpcilIGzDDcFrmlCcGDkftlbsedenbAGpFdbo/ALLA_DJ01.jpg.scaled500.jpg">
```

Comment: Isn't this removing the wrong attribute (`alt`)? I thought it was the `width` and `height` that the poster wanted to get rid of. Confused, now.

Comment: I notice more and more that OPs prefer solutions that work on text rather than documents with structure @root's solution becomes a template for removing any attribute in a document. It could even be made into a function and put into our own xml_utils module.